# How do I pass an uploaded Image to Jimp using Hapi 19?

Tags: multipartform-data, hapi, jimp

We're upgrading our Front-end and have reached a rather old piece of code which allows us to upload an image file to the back-end to be used as an avatar.

After some wrangling we have managed to persuade the `Vue.js` front-end to pass an image to the back-end via `FormData`.

The issue is that the handler is supposed to use `Jimp` to resize the image and place copies in specific directories. Unfortunately the resized images come our as 0 bytes.

Our upload route

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'Upload Routes',
  register: async (server, options) => {
    server.route([
      {
        method: 'PUT',
        path: '/uploads/user/{md_ref}/image',
        handler: handleUpload,
        options: {
          payload: {
            allow: 'multipart/form-data',
            maxBytes: 209715200,
            multipart: true,
            output: 'file',
            uploads: './src/public/images/uploads',
            parse: true
          }
        }
      }
    ])
  }
}
```

And the handler

```
async function handleUpload (req, h) {
  try {
    const path400 = './src/public/images/400/'
    const path200 = './src/public/images/200/'
    const path100 = './src/public/images/100/'
    const payload = req.payload
    const newImage = await Jimp.read(payload.file.path)
    await newImage.write(`${path400}${payload.file.filename}`)
    await newImage.write(`${path200}${payload.file.filename}`)
    await newImage.write(`${path100}${payload.file.filename}`)
    ...
```

We know that the image is being correctly uploaded to `./src/public/images/uploads` - if we rename it back to `filename.jpg` then we have a duplicate of the original.

`Jimp` appears to read newImage from `payload.file.path` as we can inspect `newImage` and see the correct dimensions etc. However whilst the `write()` function creates the new files in thec correct directories, they are all 0 bytes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that `Jimp` has been updated since the back-end was written (not really a surprise)

The solution is to use `.writeAsync()` when using `await` and not `.write()`

So the code above (abbreviated for a single write) should be

```
const path400 = './src/public/images/400/'
const payload = req.payload
const newImage = await Jimp.read(`${payload.file.path})
await newImage.writeAsync(`${path400}${payload.file.filename}`)
```